# returning an array equally spaced between two given times with a given variable x

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Currently my code is below:

```
 var dateArray = d3.time.scale()
            .domain([new Date(2013, 1, 1), new Date(2013, 1, 7)])
            .ticks(d3.time.days, 1);
```

How could I return an array of equally spaced dates between these two dates given a variable x? ie x = 10

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `ticks` from your time scale:

```
var dateArray = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2013, 1, 1), new Date(2013, 1, 7)]);
```

And use it with your `x` variable:

```
var x = 10;
var spacedDates = dateArray.ticks(x);
```

According to the documentation, `ticks()`:

> Returns representative dates from the scale's input domain. The returned tick dates are uniformly spaced (modulo irregular time intervals, such as months and leap years), have human-readable values (such as midnights), and are guaranteed to be within the extent of the input domain.

However, the length of your array is not necessarily the number you pass to `ticks`:

> If count is a number, then **approximately** count ticks will be returned. (emphasis mine)

Here is a demo:

```js
var dateArray = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2013, 1, 1), new Date(2013, 1, 7)]);
   
var x = 10;
var spacedDates = dateArray.ticks(x);
   
console.log(spacedDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

**EDIT:** To get the *exact* number of dates, you can use `invert()` and populate your own array:

```
for(var i = 0; i<x; i++){
    spacedDates.push(dateArray.invert(i));
}
```

Check the demo:

```js
var x = 10;

var dateArray = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([new Date(2013, 1, 1), new Date(2013, 1, 7)])
  .range([0, x-1]);
  
var spacedDates = [];
  
for(var i = 0; i<x; i++){
    spacedDates.push(dateArray.invert(i));
}

console.log(spacedDates);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the explanation and documentation. Makes clear sense now!

Comment: after reading the documentation as you state it returns approximately ticks, is there a method to make it return the exact input x ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried using a couple different methods to no avail. I will look over invert(), but thanks again!